# Why does jQueries trigger don't call eventListener

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a script where I add an `eventListener` with pure JavaScript like this:

```
body.addEventListener('click', track, false);
```

In my unit test I want to fire an event on an element in the `body`.

```
$('#test').trigger('click')
```

But this doesn't work. It seems only to work if I add the `eventListener` using jQuery. Also I can trigger the event with pure JavaScript.

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

 $('#test')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

So can someone explain why `trigger` doesn't work here?

Comment: Yes, `.trigger()` only triggers events added with jQuery, that's how it was designed. I don't know what kind of explanation you're looking for.

Comment: @Juhana not true: [here's a jQuery trigger firing a native bound event](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/BRYWk/). You may be thinking of thinking of [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Answer (score 2):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/BRYWk/).

Can't see all your code — it may be that `track` isn't defined, `body` isn't assigned, or there is no `#test` element in your HTML — but you missed out the first closing apostrophe in:

```
$('#test).trigger('click')
```

…which should be:

```
$('#test').trigger('click')
```